# Why oracle implicit statement caching is disabled by default?

Tags: oracle, caching, jdbc, prepared-statement, ojdbc

Why oracle implicit statement caching is disabled by default if the driver is designed with caching in mind([20 Statement and Result Set Caching](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/stmtcach.htm))? Is there a case when using the cache can lead to different behaviour?

> Oracle strongly recommends you use the implicit Statement cache.
>   Oracle JDBC drivers are designed on the assumption that the implicit
>   Statement cache is enabled. So, not using the Statement cache will
>   have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask this question to Oracle staff why they implemented it in this way that the option is disabled by default while they recommend to enable this option at the same time.

Comment: Oracle staff was in the process of answering when it was put on hold. Oh well.